# Chaining Privoxy and Shadowsocks... Privoxy actions (blocks) not working

Tags: socks-proxy, privoxy

I have privoxy as windows system proxy.
privoxy config file is as follows:

```
confdir .
logdir .
forward-socks5 / 127.0.0.1:39001 .
listen-address  127.0.0.1:8118
show-on-task-bar 0
activity-animation 0
hide-console
toggle 0
actionsfile user.action
logfile privoxy.log
debug 8192
enforce-blocks 1
```

My user.action file is

```
 { +block{Domain contains "face"} }
  .face.
```

But when I enter facebook.com in browsers, the site does not get blocked.

Why is this happening? Any ideas?